# Elephantine memory.

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence

When something is '*Elephantine*', it means that it is similar to an elephant in a certain way. Since elephants have great memory, is it alright for me to say that someone *has an elephantine memory*?

Could you also give me some examples of sentences with the word '*elephantine*'?

Thank you!

Comment: Because of the strong associations people have between elephants and long memories, and in particular because of the aphorism "an elephant never forgets", I'd say you are not risking much with "elephantine memory". Absent that connection, however, *elphantine* connotes enormity to an absurd degree: something, bloated, lumbering, inelegant. So it **would** be a risk, for example, to say "he has an elphantine brain*.

Comment: @DanBron sorry I don't understand

Comment: 'Elephantine memory' makes sense, and has been used. But it has not been used very often (according to a Google search), and 'they have a memory like an elephant' is the idiomatic choice. 'They have an elephantine memory' is the quirky-comical or ridiculously pompous choice. // You can Google for such sentences yourself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google Books search finds nearly 300 matches for "elephantine memory"—most of them in the sense of "a long and accurate memory," including this entry for the term in V.N. Sadasiva Rau, [*Sura's Idioms and Phrases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZDQm0RNq1NQC&pg=PA91&dq=%22elephantine+memory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGjve23PjLAhUjnIMKHd_PB3kQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22elephantine%20memory%22&f=false) (2006):

> **Elephantine memory** *Extremely reliable (memory)* He has an **elephantine memory** for figures.

The earliest instances of the wording go back to the [first half of the nineteenth century](https://books.google.com/books?id=OpRFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22elephantine+memory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRrbzP3_jLAhWLtIMKHTYZAuw4hAIQ6AEIPTAH#v=onepage&q=%22elephantine%20memory%22&f=false) and involve literally the memory possessed by an elephant. For example, from a [letter by Lieutenant Colonel M. Fawker](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ne0hAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA447&dq=%22elephantine+memory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF0cSC3vjLAhXmn4MKHbeFBg84ZBDoAQhNMAk#v=onepage&q=%22elephantine%20memory%22&f=false) of Dorset to *The Spectator* (March 31, 1900):

> **ELEPHANTINE MEMORY**.
>
> [To the Editor of the " Spectator."]
>
> Sir, — *À propos* of your article on "The Elephant Inquest" in the *Spectator* of February 24th, perhaps the following may interest you. An elephant was being sent up from Bombay to the Delhi Assemblage in January, 1877, by the then Governor, Sir P. Wodehouse. On the way it met a party of men, one of whom had been its mahout and had ill-treated it, as it turned out afterwards. Without any warning, it singled out this man and killed him instantly, and then escaped into the jungle, without hurting any one else. ... Sir P. Wodehouse had a young African elephant he was very fond of showing. One day it got obstreperous, and he sent for an old Indian elephant to keep it in order. It was most amusing to see the way it whacked the small one with its trunk, but it had the desired effect. It is a pity these sagacious and interesting animals should be so ill-treated at times, for they are undoubtedly very vindictive and their memory is wonderful.

But the vast majority of the many Google Books matches involve the modern figurative sense, as in this instance from [*The New Yorker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O5geAQAAMAAJ&q=%22elephantine+memory%22&dq=%22elephantine+memory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTsIy84PjLAhVquoMKHbXsDpk4ogIQ6AEIODAH) (1990):

> "I think Larissa has been used before," said Masursky, who has been a member of virtually every nomenclature committee since the space age began and has an **elephantine memory**.
>
> "But not for a satellite," Owen said. "It may have been used for a crater someplace, but it's O.K. to use it again for a moon."

As this example shows, the usage is sincere and admiring, and contains no implication of clumsiness, awkwardness, or other less-than-flattering pachydermic qualities.

Answer (score 1):

'elephantine' : "of, resembling, or characteristic of an elephant or elephants, especially in being large, clumsy, or awkward."

http://vocabdictionary.com/dictionary/translate/elephantine/elephantine-meaning-in-finnish-English

"I fear for that woman," Cynthia said as Edith squeezed by the descending elephantine shape of Gladys Turnbull.

http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/elephantine#ihSzObPYGjg2yCT2.97